# Trying to add a null byte at the end of my string in lc3 assembly

Tags: assembly, lc3

Here is my code so far:

```
   .ORIG X3000
    LEA R0, PROMPT
    PUTS

GET_INPUT
    GETC
    OUT
    ADD R5, R0, #-10    
    BRz ECHO_INPUT
    JSR STORE_INPUT 
    BR
GET_INPUT 

STORE_INPUT
    LD R5, STRING_POINTER 
    STI R0, STRING_POINTER
    ADD R5, R5, #1 
    ST R5, STRING_POINTER
    RET 
 

ECHO_INPUT
    LD R0, STRING_HEAD
    PUTS 
    HALT
PROMPT  .STRINGZ "Enter string to echo: "
STRING_POINTER  .FILL X3100
STRING_HEAD .FILL x3100
    .END
```

I understand for the string to read properly on a randomized machine, a null byte needs to be added to the end of it. I thought the HALT in the echo function would do this, but I was wrong. How could I go about adding it?

Comment: Use the subroutine with a null byte as the parameter.

Comment: FYI, `ECHO_INPUT` is not a function.  `HALT` stops the processor the instant it executes.  Also, the `puts` is *before* the `HALT`, so the execution of `HALT` cannot have any effect on the printing and the presence of `HALT` after `puts` does nothing until its execution.